# how to connect front end if using VB6.0 and backend if using SQL using local server?

Tags: connection, frontend, backend

I am fairly new to programming and would like to know that how do you connect front end and back end using local servers?

Answer (score 0):

```
1.you need to put a data control in the form then make its visibility to false
2.right click on the page and select view Code
3.in code view write the following code

imports system.data.sqlclient
dim db as database
dim rs as recordset
privete sub form1_load()
set db=opendatabase(app.path & "\db.mdb") // for connect to access database
set rs= db.openrecordset("table_name")// select table in the database
end sub



//** to connect to the sql database
dim cn as sqlconnection
cn=new SQLConnection("connection string")
cmd= new sqlcommand("sql string",cn)
cmd.connection.open
cmd.execute 
cmd.connection.close **//
```